# Unique name on name-attribute asp.net mvc in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code:

```
foreach (var questionGroups in Model.ClientQuestionGroups)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < questionGroups.Questions.Count; j++)
    {       
        <div class="test">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[j].FormAnswerId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[j].QuestionId)
            @foreach (var alternative in questionGroups.Questions[j].QuestionAlternatives)
            {
                if (alternative.NestedQuestion != null)
                {
                   nestedQuestions.Add(alternative.NestedQuestion);
                }
            }
        </div>
    }
    if (nestedQuestions.Count > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < nestedQuestions.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="nestedQuestion">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].FormAnswerId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].QuestionId)
                @foreach (var alt in nestedQuestions[i].QuestionAlternatives)
                {
                   @Html.DisplayFor(m => alt.AlternativeText)
                   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].AlternativeId, alt.Id, new { @class = "questionAlternative" });
                }
            </div>
         }
    }
}
```

This generates the following html:

```
<div class="test">
<input id="QuestionAnswers_0__FormAnswerId" type="hidden" value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" name="QuestionAnswers[0].FormAnswerId" data-val-required="Fältet FormAnswerId krävs." data-val="true">
<input id="QuestionAnswers_0__QuestionId" type="hidden" value="427d0a77-b7b7-48b0-956a-28794145e0da" name="QuestionAnswers[0].QuestionId" data-val-required="Fältet QuestionId krävs." data-val="true">
Yes
<input id="QuestionAnswers_0__AlternativeId" class="questionAlternative" type="radio" value="aabf2548-abca-4cb5-89d8-759f2d71be01" nestedquestion="895015c0-2bf0-4c5a-95c9-8d4b29671bf7" name="QuestionAnswers[0].AlternativeId" data-val-required="Fältet AlternativeId krävs." data-val="true">
No
<input id="QuestionAnswers_0__AlternativeId" class="questionAlternative" type="radio" value="91b220dc-3ef3-45a9-8369-dc1e4e2530a8" nestedquestion="" name="QuestionAnswers[0].AlternativeId">
</div>

<div class="nestedQuestion questionDiv">
<p>Testar2</p>
<p>Testar2</p>
<input id="QuestionAnswers_0__FormAnswerId" type="hidden" value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" name="QuestionAnswers[0].FormAnswerId">
<input id="QuestionAnswers_0__QuestionId" type="hidden" value="427d0a77-b7b7-48b0-956a-28794145e0da" name="QuestionAnswers[0].QuestionId">
Yes
<input id="QuestionAnswers_0__AlternativeId" class="questionAlternative" type="radio" value="aabf2548-abca-4cb5-89d8-759f2d71be01" name="QuestionAnswers[0].AlternativeId">
No
<input id="QuestionAnswers_0__AlternativeId" class="questionAlternative" type="radio" value="91b220dc-3ef3-45a9-8369-dc1e4e2530a8" name="QuestionAnswers[0].AlternativeId">
</div>
```

As you can see, the ID-attribute and Name-attribute has the same value/name. I don't want that. I want the first div to be `0`, and the nested question div to be `1` and so forth. I know this occurs because It's in the same loop.

I can't quite figure out how to solve this naming schema. Anyone who can push me into the right direction?

Comment: you can try to use counter values for your loops and then use counts as suffix for div's name ..

Comment: @NMathur: Can you give me a example?

Comment: Why is m.QuestionAnswers used twice in two different sections?  Are they each a part of a different form?

Comment: @BrianMains: QuestionAnswers belongs to a question. Each div Is a question with two or more question alternatives to choose between.

Comment: It's OK to reuse the [0] index but you have the two ID's twice, and really you should store the question ID in the question section and the answer ID in the answer section.  As long as you aren't reusing properties in the different sections, your approach will be fine.

Comment: If you change the name and id like "name_0, name_1" will be a problem in a possible POST/model binder to server. If you really want to do that, try to use Hidden instead. 
@Html.Hidden("name" + i, item.Name)

Comment: You need to show your models (your loops do not makes sense) and in any case you would not be able to bind to the model when you submit so you need to use view models that are structured correctly to represent what your trying to edit

Answer (score 1):

for (var i = 0; i < nestedQuestions.Count; i++)

change the second for loop to the following:

for (var i = 1; i < nestedQuestions.Count; i++)

But this will be bad, because when u have multiple questions and multiple nested questions they will get mixed up.

Maybe something like this is better:

```
if (nestedQuestions.Count > 0)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < nestedQuestions.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="nestedQuestion">
            @Html.Hidden("NestedQuestions", Model.QuestionAnswers[i].FormAnswerId)
             @Html.Hidden("NestedQuestions", Model.QuestionAnswers[i].QuestionId)
            @foreach (var alt in nestedQuestions[i].QuestionAlternatives)
            {
               @Html.Display("NestedQuestion", alt.AlternativeText)
               @Html.RadioButton("NestedQuestion", m.QuestionAnswers[i].AlternativeId, alt.Id, new { @class = "questionAlternative" });
            }
        </div>
     }
}
```

This will generate what u want, but in your Post action u should have some property to catch these nested objects. The defaultModelBinder will bind it when u make the names match.

Greetings,

Sven

Comment: No, that don't work. I can't change the loop in the way you want because i < nestedQuestion.Count will allways return false. If I add a nested question to the list, the Count results in 1. 1 < 1 is false..

Comment: Hehe... that is not what u asked. U could screw around with the statement or create an extra if statement at the end of the for loop and make it exit on some statement u prefer. All not preferable and as i mentioned this all is better be solved at the server side, but as you dont want that my second part of the last post is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you building this up? I guess this is your View? In my opinion this is not best practice, because u put too much logic in there. Is it not possible to calculate this within your business layer/ mvc (controller). All the if statements are too much. Within MVC u should avoid as much logic inside your view as possible. When i fix that part u can do a foreach in a foreach without the for loops. Makes it a lot more simple to manage.

Are the for loops even necessary in the first place?

Greetings,

S..

Comment: Btw... If u just want the second 0 to be 1. Just let the for loop start at 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 0):

No example was in mind .. but hopw this can help ..

```
@{ int testCounter = 0; int nestedQuestionsCounter = 0; }

@foreach (var questionGroups in Model.ClientQuestionGroups)
{

        for (var j = 0; j < questionGroups.Questions.Count; j++)
        {       
        <div class="@(testCounter)test">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[j].FormAnswerId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[j].QuestionId)
            @foreach (var alternative in questionGroups.Questions[j].QuestionAlternatives)
            {
                if (alternative.NestedQuestion != null)
                {
                   nestedQuestions.Add(alternative.NestedQuestion);
                }
            }
        </div>

    }

    if (nestedQuestions.Count > 0)
    {
        nestedQuestionsCounter = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < nestedQuestions.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="@(nestedQuestionsCounter)nestedQuestion">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].FormAnswerId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].QuestionId)
                @foreach (var alt in nestedQuestions[i].QuestionAlternatives)
                {
                   @Html.DisplayFor(m => alt.AlternativeText)
                   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].AlternativeId, alt.Id, new { @class = "questionAlternative" });
                }
            </div>
            nestedQuestionsCounter++;
         }
    }
    testCounter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But It don't work quite well.